# Using Stirling's Approximation to calculate how many ways to distribute certain objects among a group of children.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, factorial

I have written the question and my solution to each part below. I would like to please know if you think they are correct and if not what is the correct approach? Thank you so much!

**Question**

> The kids in a kindergarten are going outdoors for a walk. But before they can go out into the winter weather, they need to put on their hat, gloves and boots. Unfortunately, the organization of the kindergarten is a bit chaotic. Assuming that there are $N$ children in the kindergarten and that $N$ is sufficiently large to justify Stirling's approximation,
>
> a) Calculate how many ways there are to distribute $N$ hats over the $N$ children, when every child receives exactly one hat. Call this number $g_{\text{hats}}$ and use Stirling's approximation for $\ln g_{\text{hats}}$:
>
> b) Calculate how many ways there are to distribute $2N$ gloves over the $2N$ hands, one glove per hand. Call this number $g_{\text{gloves}}$ and use Stirling's approximation for $\ln g_{\text{gloves}}$.
>
> c) Calculate how many ways there are to distribute $2N$ boots ($N$ pairs of boots) over $N$ children ($2N$ feet), with the requirement that every left foot gets a left-footed boot and every right foot gets a right-footed boot. Note that one child is allowed to get boots from different pairs. Call this number gboots and use Stirling's approximation for $\ln g_{\text{boots}}$.
>
> d) What is the value of $\ln(g_{\text{gloves}}/g_{\text{boots}})$ for large $N$?
>
> N.B., the children, hats, gloves and boots are all distinguishable.

**Solution**

(a) Using Stirling's approximation, we can approximate the natural logarithm of $N!$ as:
$$
\ln(N!) \approx N\ln(N) - N
$$

(b) Using Stirling's approximation, we can approximate the natural logarithm of $(2N)!$ as:
$$
\ln\bigl((2N)!\bigr) \approx 2N\ln(2N) - 2N
$$

(c) So the total number of ways to distribute the $2N$ boots is: $1 \cdot N!$ Using Stirling's approximation, we can approximate the natural logarithm of this number as:
$$
\ln(1 \cdot N!) \approx N \ln(N) - N
$$

So, in this case, the approximation for $\ln(g_{\text{boots}}) = \ln(1 \cdot N!) \approx N\ln(N)-N$.

(d)
\begin{align} 
\ln(g_{\text{gloves}}) 
&= \ln\bigl((2N)!\bigr) 
= \ln\bigl( (2N) \cdot (2N-1) (2N-2) \cdots 2 \cdot 1 \bigr) \\ \ln(g_{\text{boots}}) 
&= \ln(N!) = \ln(N (N-1) (N-2) \cdots 2 \cdot 1) \\ 
\ln \left(\frac{g_{\text{gloves}}}{g_{\text{boots}}}\right) 
&= \ln(g_{\text{gloves}}) - \ln(g_{\text{boots}}) = \ln(2N)) - \ln(N) 
\end{align}

We can use the Stirling's approximation for large $N$,
$$
\ln(x!) \approx x\ln(x) - x
$$
so
$$
\ln \left(\frac{g_{\text{gloves}}}{g_{\text{boots}}}\right) 
\approx \bigl(2N\ln(2N)- 2N\bigr) - \bigl(N\ln(N) - N\bigr).
$$

As $N$ becomes large, the difference between $2N$ and $N$ is insignificant and the value of $\ln(g_{\text{gloves}}/g_{\text{boots}})$ is
approximately $N\ln(2)$ for large $N$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for formatting math on this site.

Comment: LOL at *there are N children in the kindergarten and that N is sufficiently large to justify Stirling's approximation*

Comment: @SammyBlack: The bounds due to Robbins may already be sufficiently good for large kindergardens ;-)

Comment: There exist gloves with no distinguished front- and backside, so you can wear a glove on the left and right hand. On the other hand, we have gloves with distinguished front and back. What type are we looking at here?

Comment: Now that I thought about it, I'm pretty sure Stirling's approximation is sufficient for all practical purposes, and I'm also convinced that the gloves do not have distinguished front and back sides. So we can put a glove on both the left hand or the right hand. Otherwise Part d) would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We have $N$ hats for $N$ children, so we get $N!$ outcomes.
2. For the gloves, I'll consider two options.

   1. We have $N$ pairs of right glove and left glove, then we have $N!$ options to put the right gloves on the right hands and $N!$ options to put the left gloves on the left hands, yielding $N!^2$ gloves.
   2. We have $2N$ gloves, and each glove fits on all hands. Then we can freely choose, yielding $(2N)!$ gloves.
3. The boots are the same as Option 1 for the gloves, meaning $N!^2$.

Using Option 1 we have $N!^5$ options in total, using Option 2 we have $N!^3(2N)!$ options in total.

Since we look at a kindergarden, we work with the fairly precise approximation $\exp(\frac{1}{12n+1})f(n)\le n!\le\exp(\frac{1}{12n})f(n)$, where $f(n)=\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$.
This gives $\frac{1}{12N+1}\le\ln(N!)-\ln(f(N))\le\frac{1}{12N}$ for the hats, $\frac{2}{12N+1}\le\ln(N!^2)-2\ln(f(N))\le\frac{2}{12N}$ for the boots and gloves using Option 1, and $\frac{1}{24N+1}\le\ln((2N)!)-\ln(f(2N))\le\frac{1}{24N}$ for the gloves using Option 2.

Using Option 1 we get $\ln(N!^2/N!^2)=0$ for the ratio. Using Option 2 we get $\frac{1}{24N+1}-\frac{2}{12N}\le\ln((2N)!/N!^2)-\ln(f(2N)/f(N)^2)\le\frac{1}{24N}-\frac{2}{12N+1}$. A closer look further gives $\ln(f(2N)/f(N)^2)=\ln\frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2N)}(\frac{2N}{2})^{2N}}{\sqrt{2\pi N}^2(\frac{N}{e})^{2N}}=\ln\frac{2^{2N}}{\sqrt{\pi N}}$.

Finally, here are the numbers for plausible numbers of children. Notice that the error bounds computed above go in the same direction, meaning we know that $N!>f(N)$. The actual approximation error for $\ln(N!)$ is $\frac{1}{12N}-\frac{1}{12N+1}=\frac{1}{12N(12N+1)}$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the delayed reply. This was really helpful

Comment: We're not in a hurry, you're welcome!